# IPv6 between 2 interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, usb, ipv6

I want to connect a PC with another device running linux with a USB cable (ethernet over USB with both nodes directly connected with the cable).

The following works with IPv4.

```
#PC : 

sudo ifconfig ens32u2u2c2 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0

#Device :

ifconfig usb0 192.168.1.101 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

As this is working (both nodes can ping each other), i thought IPv6 would be straightforward, but the following is not working :

```
#PC :

sudo ifconfig ens32u2u2c2 inet6 add 0e::12
# result : inet6 e::12  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>


#Device :

ifconfig usb0 e::13/128
# result  : inet6 addr: e::13/128 Scope:Global
```

While both addresses seem to be setup when checking with `ifconfig usb0` and `ifconfig ens32u2u2c2`, i cannot get to ping the device from the PC nor the PC from the device, while this works in IPv4.

Any idea why ?

Comment: Why are you configuring the address as an /128 (single host)? That's a significant difference from your IPv4 configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but is it relevant to reach a state of connectivity ? What do you recommend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration does not provide the devices any route to each other.

In IPv4, you're adding addresses with a /24 subnet (mask 255.255.255.0). This tells the devices that all other addresses from this /24 – the whole 0…255 – are reachable directly on this interface.

In IPv6, you're adding addresses with a /128 subnet (which on IPv4 would be equivalent to using /32 or 255.255.255.255). This specifies a subnet that has exactly one host (itself), so it doesn't generate a route that would tell it how to reach the other host.

You need to:

- a) configure addresses using a shorter subnet mask, e.g. `/64` is traditional for Ethernet, and `/126` or `/127` is somewhat common for links containing exactly two hosts.

  ```
  ip addr add e::12/64 dev ens32u2u2c2
  ```

  (This will automatically produce an e::/64 route.)
- or b) manually add a route towards the other host:

  ```
  ip route add e::13 dev ens32u2u2c2
  ```

Comment: This worked, it was the first time i got to use IPv6 and i was not too familiar with this notation. Thanks for making this clearer for me.